# How to determine n-node connected subnetworks in a given directed graph?

Tags: graph-theory, network

For a given directed graph, I want to determine all 4-node connected subnetworks. Do we have any specific algorithm designed for this for calculating 4-node connected subnetworks?

Comment: Well, you can just test for each subset of the vertices whether the induced subgraph is $4$-connected. In a sense, you can't do much better than this, since there may be exponentially many $4$-connected subgraphs.

Comment: Okk fyn, I got it. But I want to know if any algorithm exists which determines all n-node connected subnetworks if directed graph is provided as a input parameter.